# Double integral where integration limit of the inner integral is integration variable of outer integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to replicate a paper. I want to prove that:
$$\sigma^{-1} \int_t^T k \int_s^T e^{-\rho (z-s)} x(z) dz ds = k \int_t^T m(z-t) x(z) dz$$
where $m(s) = (\sigma \rho)^{-1} (1-e^{-\rho s})$. In other words, I need to solve a double integral where the integration limit of the inner integral is the variable of integration of the outer integral.

Here is the section of the paper where the calculation is done:
[image]

My approach would be to swap the integrals:
\begin{align}
&\sigma^{-1} \int_t^T k \int_s^T e^{-\rho (z-s)} x(z) dz ds \\
&k \int_s^T \sigma^{-1} \int_t^T  e^{-\rho (z-s)} ds x(z) dz  \\
\end{align}
Then doing the inner integration:
\begin{align}
&k \int_s^T \sigma^{-1} \left[(\sigma \rho)^{-1} (1-e^{-\rho s})\right]_t^T x(z) dz  \\
\end{align}
But here I get stuck.i have also tried integration by parts but it doesn't work either. I think I need to substitute some variables, but I don't see why. Could anyone help?

Comment: Is there something you haven't told us about the boundary terms in the integral, I'm struggling to see where the $1-...$ part comes form in your inner integral

Comment: I have added the reference section of the paper. I obtain the 1- if I use integration by parts on the inner integral, but still cannot solve it as in the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider the domain of integration. This is a triangle in the $z-s$ plane, bounded by $s=t$, $z=T$ and $z=s$. When you exchange integrals you need to re-describe this region so the outer integral limits do not depend on the inner integral variable of integration. Specifically: $$\int_t^T\Big(\int_s^T f(z, s) dz\Big) ds=\int_t^T\Big(\int_t^z f(z, s) ds\Big) dz.$$  I hope this is enough for you to complete the integral yourself.